# Is this value on the top right of the matrix called Hadamard Coefficient?

Tags: fft

Here I have a matrix.
a=[5 10;5 10]

I have applied Fourier transformation using fft2 command on it in matlab 
b=fft2(a)

After this command result will be 
        b=
              30   -10 ;
              0     0

I know at the top left 30 is the DC component which is the average intensity. But I'm not sure about -10 value. Is this Hadamard coefficient ?
Thank You

Comment: I believe that term (Hadamard coefficient) is only used for matrices containing only 1s,-1s and zeros. But better ask that question in the Math or Signal Processing sites.